# PJSIP library updation for android

Tags: java, android, pjsip

In Android Studio implemented pjsip library using SWIG. The version of pjsip implemented is 2.6. This is old version. 2.10 is latest version of pjsip library. I would like to update it to latest. Before I have used ubuntu with linux os. But now changed to cent os 7.
My doubts are,

1. Can I able to update pjsip library from cent OS 7
2. How can I update pjsip library?
   Go throughed pjsip documentation but I am not able to understand about updating pjsip library.
   Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you try to compile it by ./configure-android and then make dep && make clean && make ?

Comment: @Oleg No. In pjsip documentation given as ``` cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
$ export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path_to_android_ndk_dir 
$ ./configure-android
$ make dep && make clean && make``` mentioned to go through pjsip directory. Only there is JniLibs(Inside of this contains "libpjsua2.so" files) folder inside Android project. Loading library like this ```System.loadLibrary("openh264"); System.loadLibrary("pjsua2");``` in Android project.  So I dont have pjsip library folder in local.

Comment: after you do make dep && make clean && make you need to cd to /pjsip-apps/src/swig/java and execute make here. only after this .so should appear in jniLibs

Comment: @Oleg okay. able to understand that. My doubt is, where do I  need to execute make dep&& make clean && make.

Comment: you need to do it in root of pjsip project directory. the same place where you do call ./configure-android

Comment: @Oleg I have tried ```./configure-android``` in the path of my android project of pjsip. But got as ```bash: ./configure-android: No such file or directory```

Comment: no, you need to call ./configure-android in pjsip source code project which you download from https://www.pjsip.org/download.htm . make dep && make clean && make you need to call there as well

Comment: @Oleg thank you.. Now I followed up the steps. For ```make``` command in the path /pjsip-apps/src/swig/java got failure message as ```output/pjsua2_wrap.o: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [android/app/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libpjsua2.so] Error 1```  Do you have any idea about this error?

Comment: did you make config_site.h with #define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1 ?

Comment: @Oleg No.. I didn't know about that. Do I need to do any change regarding that?

Comment: as it is described here https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android. you need to create config_site.h file, add lines #define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>, put this file to pjlib/include/pj directory. then configure and compile

Comment: have you managed to resolve it?

Comment: @Oleg thank you for asking. Didn't get any errors when I used this ```TARGET_ABI=arm64-v8a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags``` instead of```./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags```. And inside pjsip folder got  two folders ```arm64-v8a ---> libc++_shared.so  and  x86   ---->  libc++_shared.so,  libpjsua2.so```.   As you can see my target abi is arm64-v8a but only able to find libpjsua2.so inside x86. Also when tried with target abi as  armeabi, got aborted.  And when I tried abi with ```armeabi-v7a``` not got error but no jni is generated.

Comment: better not to use armeabi, it's deprecated arch. for others i usually do like this: |for armv7a| APP_PLATFORM=android-19 TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android |for x86| 
APP_PLATFORM=android-19 TARGET_ABI=x86 ./configure-android |for arm64|
APP_PLATFORM=android-21 TARGET_ABI=arm64-v8a ./configure-android |for x86_64| 
APP_PLATFORM=android-21 TARGET_ABI=x86_64 ./configure-android